# Count Based on Multiple Columns

Tags: python, bash

I have a large log file that has user IDs and IP addresses. I'm trying to determine the best way to view how many user IDs a particular IP logged into.

Initially I thought I could do this via cut, sort, and uniq on the command line but I'm not getting the output I'm desiring. A Python or bash solution would be ideal.

Below is an example of the file:

```
eric 1.1.1.1
eric 1.1.1.1
brian 1.1.1.1
jeff 1.1.1.1
eric 2.2.2.2
bob 3.3.3.3
jeff 3.3.3.3
eric 1.1.1.1
eric 1.1.1.1
eric 4.4.4.4
peter 4.4.4.4
```

I'd like the output to show this type of information:

```
eric - 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, 4.4.4.4
brian - 1.1.1.1
jeff - 1.1.1.1, 3.3.3.3
bob - 3.3.3.3
peter - 4.4.4.4
```

As well as:

```
1.1.1.1 - eric, brian, jeff
2.2.2.2 - eric
3.3.3.3 - bob, jeff
4.4.4.4 - peter
```

As it matures, I'll have to create a variable for exclusion IPs where we can maybe say 1.1.1.1 is a NAT and trusted so we can ignore it since multiple users would be coming from it.

Appreciate push in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm I would try loading the file into a `pandas.DataFrame`, then `grouby()` the name column, and finally get the unique values of each group.

Comment: Do you want a full script of just some recommendations?

Comment: Does the input have to be as is, or can you use tuples or a list or something?

Comment: @timotree - I'm down for either. If you want to write the code that would be great and I'll dissect it later to figure out what to do. However if you want to just give basic recommendations that's fine as well.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 - That is the input as I receive it from the server. I could look at modifying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following script, written in the input-process-output style.

Some notes:

The `fileinput` module allows you to specify a single input filename on the command line, multiple filenames, or no filename at all (it will use stdin in that case).

The `defaultdict` allows you to collects sets of data conveniently.

`', '` join produces the comma-separated output lines you want.

Using a generator expression `(line.split() for line ...)` instead of a list comprehension `[line.split() for line ...]` saves memory (you said these were big files). If you used a list comprehension, you would have the all of the data stored in memory twice.

As the code matures, you can switch to `argparse` for controlling the new features you add.

```py
import fileinput
import collections

# Input the data
raw_data = (line.split() for line in fileinput.input())

# Process the data
name2ip = collections.defaultdict(set)
ip2name = collections.defaultdict(set)
for name, ip in raw_data:
    name2ip[name].add(ip)
    ip2name[ip].add(name)

# Output the data
for name, ips in name2ip.items():
    print '%s - %s'%(name, ', '.join(ips))

for ip, names in ip2name.items():
    print '%s - %s'%(ip, ', '.join(names))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response Rob. I'll play around with it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks again for the code. I started playing with it today and it does a great job of providing the output I desire. Also, thank you for the detailed information as to what everything does, this will be very helpful in the future. The only thing I need to do now is sort the output where the name with the most unique IPs shows at the time and on the IP section, the IP with the most names shows at the time.

Comment: I tried to run this code on my actual logs and it failed saying "ValueError: too many values to unpack" on the "for name, ip in raw_data:" line. I have ~20 log.gz files that are around 80 MB each compressed. I tried just doing one with the line "zcat log_file.log.gz | code.py" when I got the error. This syntax works fine on my small tests.

Comment: That probably means that your log files contain data that doesn't match the form you've given. Find the lines that are odd and modify your program accordingly.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks.